# ¿Cómo obtener la posición de una variable k arreglo Estado L, cuando el valor de k en esa posición es True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola quisiera saber que me aconsejan para obtener la posición, es decir i, cuando la variable k se igual a True. He planteado este código, pero lo que me retorna son solo 0.

```
k = False
      j = 0
      while k != False:
            for i in range(len(EstadoL)):
                  k = EstadoL[i]
            j = j+1
      print(j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que la función `enumerate` te sea útil. Normalmente se usa así:

```
arr = ["a","b","c"]

for i,d in enumerate(arr):
    if d == "c":
        print(i, ": es el índice del elemento 'c'")
```

Comment: Vale intentare con la función que mencionas, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En Python la indentación es parte de la sintaxis. Probablemente tu script deba ser escrito asi:

```
k = False
j = 0
while k != False:
    for i in range(len(EstadoL)):
        k = EstadoL[i]
    j = j+1
print(j)
```

El problema es que `k` parte en `False`, por lo que la ejecución no entra nunca al `while`.

No se ve muy lógico asi. Probablemente la condición sea la inversa: `while not k`, es decir, mientras `k` sea falso.

Ahora, `k` solo cambia dentro del `if`. Es es el lugar para recordar el valor de `i` en la variable `j`, que debe ser inicializa con `-1`, pues `0` es un indice válido.

¿Cuando recordar el valor? Cuando el `EstadoL[i]` sea `True` ... no tiene sentido cambiar `k` de `False` a `False`. Ahi agregamos otro `if`

Esta versión debe estar más cerca de lo que pretendes

```
k = False
j = -1
while not k:
    for i in range(len(EstadoL)):
        if EstadoL[i]:
            k = EstadoL[i]
            j = i

print(j)
```

Así la función recuerda la última ocurrencia `True` en `EstadoL`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, no había caído en cuenta que ambos estados estaban en False. Intentare de esa manera, gracias.